# Is there any way to make base view component ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In rc1 you can make BaseViewComponent and then inherit it and use it without any problems like baseController, but after migrating my project to rc2 I recieve that error Could: not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component 'ForumSystem.Web.ViewComponents.BaseViewComponent'.
Is there any way to do that in rc2?

Comment: Please display your culprit code...

Comment: This problem still persists in Asp.Net Core 2.1 which is the current latest version as of June 2018.  And the currently accepted answer still works great.  I'm going to edit the question title to remove the reference to RC2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Having the same problem I red the documentation and found that "view components must be public, non-nested, and non-abstract classes", so I made my base class abstract and this solved my problem. This is a workaround and not a solution for everyone, but worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me as well.  Maybe it is just me, but this also feels like a workaround. Hopefully MS will add a way to data annotate a ViewComponent class to exclude it from the runtime component validation

Comment: Well. I'll take it!